# Error INTERNAL from Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

There is *myFunction* in Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
const myFunctionHandler = (params, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return admin
      .database()
      .ref("checks")
      .push(params)
      .then((r) => resolve(r))
      .catch((e) => reject(e));
};
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall(myFunctionHandler);
```

this is how I call it from the client:

```
  functions()
    .httpsCallable('myFunction')({
      myParam: true,
    })
    .then(resp => console.log(resp))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

In the Firebase Cloud Functions these are the logs:

```
Function execution started
Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Function.mapValues (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13426:7)
at encode (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:183:18)
at encode (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:157:16)
at /workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13427:38
at /workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4925:15
at baseForOwn (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
at baseForOwn (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
at Function.mapValues (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13426:7)
Function execution took 2438 ms, finished with status code: 500
```

After 2438ms the data is entered correctly in Firebase Realtime Database but the response gives `[Error: INTERNAL]`. Why?

**[EDIT]**

I've tried to copy the *same* database push function in the client like this:

```
database()
      .ref()
      .child(`checks`)
      .push(params)
      .then(r => resolve(r))
      .catch(e => reject(e));
```

and the response I have is: `https://myApp.firebaseio.com/checks/-MHABiZl5lsDBLSP22-3` that is a positive feedback that tells me the info are stored correctly.

I aspect the same positive response from the Cloud Functions **BUT** what I have is the `[Error: INTERNAL]`.

Receiving (from the function in the Firebase Cloud Functions) an Error as response the idea I have is that the info are not stored correctly.

Comment: There's not really enough information here.  What **exactly** are you expecting to send to the client?  Have you tried logging what you're sending before you send it?  It might be helpful if you review what `push()` returns. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#push

Comment: The ```push()``` works perfectly on the client. On the FCF return this Error. I aspect to have as return the http link as response (as the link you shared), instead that internal error. The params are not the issue because I see them after in the db...

Comment: What **exactly** are you expecting to send to the client?

Comment: I would offer this information sine I do not see the area of your code that throws the exception. I see the general error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561349/firebase-unhandled-error-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded

Comment: @DougStevenson I aspect to have as response the http link as described in here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#push).

Comment: @MrTech Thank you for your comment. There is this INTERNAL error when I use push(). If I retrive some data there are no problems.

Comment: @DougStevenson I just need to have a positive response from the push but I got ```Error: INTERNAL``` and I can't understand what's wrong here... Any idea?

Comment: I still don't understand what you're expecting the client to receive.  Please edit the question to be specific.  A JSON object?  If so, what data?  Be specific.

Comment: @DougStevenson, thank you. OK, edited it: I really hope now to have explained the issue better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same function gives different response from ether client or server.
In the FCF I just avoid it to parse the response of the push.
In the client it returns the https link as described in the google documentation.

Be sure also the localhost:5001 Node server is not running. In my case interfered.

Answer (score 1):

Callable functions send a JSON payload to the client.  That's all they can send.  When you return a promise from a callable function, it will attempt to serialize the object resolved from the promise.  The object you're trying to send (the result of a [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#push) is a [ThennableReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.ThenableReference)) is too complex for serialization, so it fails.  It contains self-referential links, which causes the error you see.

Your question still doesn't indicate **exactly** what the JSON payload is supposed to be.  You're going to have to figure out what that is, and send only that object to the client.  It obviously can't be a ThennableReference.  If you need to convert that to something, figure out how to convert it, and send that object instead.

Comment: The JSON in the payload is ```{ myParam: true }```

Comment: and this payload is correctly stored in Realtime Firebase. The response gives that error.
Thanks, I will try to read more about ThennableReference

Comment: Thank you for your support and your videos. Really great job!