# Maximum call stack size exceeded for simple identity function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In keeping with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815659/error-internal-from-firebase-cloud-function), I am sending a simple well-defined json object and returning a simple well-defined json object from my simple cloud function. Here is the cloud function code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp(); // (Apparently you don't need to pass any config values here?)

export const sendMessage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    return {
      data,
      context
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('aborted', error);
  }
});
```

Here is my web app's invoking code:

```
 const sendMessage_CF = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sendMessage');

  const sendMessage = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await sendMessage_CF({ body: 'test message' });
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error', error);
    }
  };
```

The resulting logs are:

```
 Function execution took 1138 ms, finished with status code: 500 
 sendMessage
Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object (<anonymous>) at 
/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4919:24 at baseForOwn 
(/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24) at Function.mapValues 
(/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13426:7) at encode 
(/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:184:18) at 
/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13427:38 at 
/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4925:15 at baseForOwn 
(/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24) at Function.mapValues 
(/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13426:7) at encode 
(/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:184:18)
```

It's such a simple function, basically hello world, so....I can't really say what the problem is.

`baseForOwn` seems to be a lodash internal implementation of something akin to `forEach` for object keys, but I don't know what `Object (<anonymous>)` is. Maybe I should `console.log` the parameters the function receives.

**EDIT**: So I added this line to the top of the cloud function:

```
  console.log('PARAMS', data, context);
```

And what happened is 1 invocation added *50* new logs. Oddly though, none of them mention "PARAMS" or log an entire object. It seems like every one is one attribute from `data` or `context`, maybe, as if a console.log had been called on every key in each of those. The plot thickens??

[image: my logs]

Actually, the last logged bit is this:

```
uid: 'J0xMj8OVn4Voc6yb547itgjt2iC3' } } }
```

It's as though it broke the log statement up by newlines! I'm so confused by this. Not to mention my initial "PARAMS" isn't included anywhere. For what it's worth, if I `console.log` a string literal by itself without data/context, it logs that correctly, once per invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`context`, which is a [CallableContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext) object, is not as simple as you imagine it to be.  The Firebase SDK on the function side is having problems serializing that as JSON, probably because it contains self-referencing data that's causing an infinite loop.  Just remove it from the response, or pick out the more clearly simple data within it that you would like for the client to receive.

Comment: Shoot. I should have tried returning something different to see if the problem lay therein. I didn't think of that. Thank you. Apparently the same is true of `data` though, since I got the same error when I removed `context`. EDIT: NEVERMIND, must have been a caching issue. problem solved!