# Firebase : Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When trying to add new item (request) for a collection in my Firestore, Although The item is properly inserted to the collection - I'm getting an error that I can't figure.

*updated*

> Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> at isLength (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:11739:22) at
> isArrayLike (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:11359:31) at keys
> (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13333:14) at
> /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4920:21 at baseForOwn
> (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24) at Function.mapValues
> (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13426:7) at encode
> (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:184:18)
> at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13427:38 at
> /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4925:15 at baseForOwn
> (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)

HTML

```
<!-- new request modal -->
  <div class="new-request">
    <div class="modal">
      <h2>New request</h2>
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="request" placeholder="request...">
        <button>Add</button>
        <p class="error"></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

app.js

```
// add a new request
const requestForm = document.querySelector(".new-request form");
const requestModal = document.querySelector(".new-request");
requestForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const addRequest = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("addRequest");
  addRequest({
    text: requestForm.request.value,
  })
  .then(() => {
    requestForm.reset();
    requestModal.classList.remove("open");
    requestForm.querySelector(".error").textContent = "";
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    requestForm.querySelector(".error").textContent = error.message;
  });
});
```

index.js (firebase functions) updated*

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

// auth trigger (user sign up)
exports.newUserSignup = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // for background triggers you must return a value/promise
  return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
    email: user.email,
    upvotedOn: [],
  });
});

// auth trigger (user deleted)
exports.userDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
  // for background triggers you must return a value/promise
  const doc = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid);
  return doc.delete();
});

// http callable function (adding a request)
exports.addRequest = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "unauthenticated",
      "only authenticated users can add requests"
    );
  }
  if (data.text.length > 30) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "invalid-argument",
      "request must be no more than 30 characters long"
    );
  }
  return admin.firestore().collection("requests").add({
    text: data.text,
    upvotes: 0,
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly, I cannot reproduce. Is it a client-side or server-side error?

Comment: @LouisCoulet error from chrome console:
service.ts:160 POST https://us-central1-requests-demo-74dd6.cloudfunctions.net/addRequest 500

Comment: As said, it must be something outside of the code that you have posted. Do you see somethink in Firebase console > Functions > Logs ?

Comment: @LouisCoulet Yes, Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Great, that narrows the issue to your index.js file. Have you copied its entire content here? Also, nothing else to point at the callstack in the logs?

Comment: It is still working fine for me. Sorry I cannot help you more. I suggest you try sparkling logs: ```functions.logger.log("call addRequest");``` or debug locally using the emulators to understand what is happening.

Comment: @LouisCoulet Don't know if it is helpful, but at the chrome network tab there is a double call for addRequest, perhaps that's the issue ?

Comment: No, that's normal, probably one OPTIONS and one POST requests? This is the CORS mechanism.

Comment: @LouisCoulet maybe the node engine version ? using 8 right now (free plan)

Comment: I cannot say. Did you get some info with the logs?

Comment: @LouisCoulet I have some updates: 
1)Tried various headers & different data but still throwing the 500 internal server error on post requests to firebase cloud functions.
2)Tried the firebase emulator (local firebase functions debugger) and it works without errors.
Thoughts ?

Comment: Hi Moshe. I suggest you to log the callstack in addRequest, in order to pinpoint the problem, instead of trying to guess!

Comment: @LouisCoulet The comment was too long.. so i've updated the post above, have a look and thank you.

Comment: Ok, so it seems to be a similar issue to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52569728/6016470 I'll try to explain in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52569728/6016470
You should not directly return the Promise<DocumentReference> produced by your call to firestore as the result of your Cloud Function. This is because a DocumentReference is not intended for being sent back as it is not serializable (your error message comes from lodash failing to serialize due to circular references).

So in order to send serializable result, you should modify your functions as such:

```
exports.addRequest = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ... 
  return admin.firestore().collection("requests").add({
    text: data.text,
    upvotes: 0,
  }).then(doc => {
    return doc.id;
  });
});
```

This way, your Cloud Function now returns a Promise<string>, so it can send back its result to your client.

Comment: Thank for the explanation! I have a bonus question - You said that the code works on your side before the suggested solution, how is that ?

Comment: Good to hear! I think it may be due to the difference in node or npm packages versions. With you initial code, with node v12 and current packages, Firebase is able to serialize the DocumentReference and send it back. I would still suggest to use the solution above as this object does not look intended for serialization.