# Firebase firestore : Unhandled Rejection (RangeError): Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, redux-thunk

Started playing around with `createAsyncThunk` for learning purpose, decided to implement a shopping cart with firebase firestore but I ran into problems when trying to implement pagination in my react app.

How should I return the last visible state into my redux state during the initial load and subsequent load (infinite loading)

I am basing on code from redux tutorial sandbox :https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux-essentials-example-app/tree/checkpoint-3-postRequests/?from-embed, but instead of connecting to a fake api, I am using firebase firestore.

Code to fetch product from firestore : ProductSlice.js

```js
const InitialState = {
   products : [],
   status: 'idle',
   error: null,
   last: null, //to hold lastVisible when fetching data from firestore
}

export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(types.RECEIVE_PRODUCTS, async (limit) => {
   const resp = await fire_base_product.firestore()
      .collection(collection_name).orderBy('id').limit(limit)

   let result = resp.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1] //how set this to redux state

      const products = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc)=> {
         return { ...doc.data()}
      })

      return { 
         products: products, 
         lastVisible: lastVisible
      };
   })

   return result;
}
```

I am not quite sure on how to set this `lastVisible` data back into redux state, is it possible to do that with reference?

#Edit:

Tried to return both product list and last visible as an array and assign lastVisible in createSlice as stated below:

```js
const productSlice = createSlice({
   name:'products',
   initialState: 
   reducers: {},
   extraReducers:{
      [fetchProducts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
         state.products = state.products.concat(action.payload.products)
         state.last = action.payload.lastVisible // this causes call stack error
      }

   }
});
```

With the above coding, two error will be reported if I run react app,

1. Trying to assign non serialize value into redux state
   [image: error message: non-serialize value]
2. Maximum call stack size exceeded in firestore
   [image: call stack size exceeded]

I then tried to add middleware serializableCheck during create configuration as below:

```js
export default configureStore({
   middlleware: getDefaultMiddlleWare({
      serializableCheck: {
         //ignore action type
         ignoredActions : ['RECEIVE_PRODUCTS/fulfilled']
         // ignore path
         ignoredPath: ['products.last']
      }
   }),
   ... // reducer codes
})
```

Even though now I have dismissed the first error, call stack exceeded still exists. Does anyone knows why this is happening ? Feel free to discuss if there is any workaround on this. Thanks.

## Edit 2

Similar approach works when using context but does not work when using redux. Do I need to wrap return in promise as suggested in [Firebase Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561349/firebase-unhandled-error-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not managed to find a way to save `lastVisible`, but I found a workaround by just keeping track of the last retrieve id of my firestore data by saving it into redux state.

```js
export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(types.RECEIVE_PRODUCTS, async (limit) => {
   const resp = await fire_base_product.firestore()
      .collection(collection_name).orderBy('id').limit(limit)

   let result = resp.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      var lastVisible = limit - 1; //only keep track of ID so we can avoid saving un-serialize coded

      const products = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc)=> {
         return { ...doc.data()}
      })

      return { 
         products: products, 
         lastVisible: lastVisible
      };
   })

   return result;
}
```

And when during fetch of additional data we can then access the state by using getState() as below:

```js
export const fetchMoreProducts = createAsyncThunk(types.LOAD_MORE_PRODUCTS, async (limit, {getState}) => {
    const last = getState().products.last

    var newProducts = await firebase_product.firestore()
        .collection('store_products').orderBy('id')
        .startAfter(last).limit(limit)

    const result = newProducts.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            var lastVisible = last + limit;

            const products = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                return { ...doc.data() }
            })

            return {
                products : products, 
                lastVisible: lastVisible
            }
        })

    // return retrieved data from firebase 
    return result
})
```

But doing this, I could skip the serialization check config all together as well. Not sure if this is the correct way, but this is how I got pagination working. Feel free to let me know if there is other way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

This error will come if you store non-serializable object in redux store!

> > if you are getting some non-serializable data from firebase, serialize it before storing it in redux store!

```js
const nonSerializable = firestore().collection().doc(uid).get().data();
// if using this nonSerializable object in reducer, serialized it using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())
const serializable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nonSerializable))
```

Answer (score 0):

you should save last visible path not the whole data like this

```
const lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1].ref.path
```