# Firebase Cloud functions "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is my firebase cloud function. It's meant to increment a counter when the user taps a button in my iOS app. The function operates currently but I get the error "Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at encode". The function is called in viewDidLoad (the destination view after the button press).

```js
exports.categoryOpened = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const categoryUUID = data.categoryUUID;
  const countryCode = data.countryCode;

  // Get the current date and hour
  const date = new Date();
  const dd = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
  const mm = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
  const yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  const hour = date.getHours();

  const path = "analytics/"+
    countryCode +
    "/categories/" +
    categoryUUID +
    "/categoryOpened/" +
    dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy +
    "/" + hour;

  // Increment the count at the appropriate location in the database
  return admin.database(analyticsDb).ref(path).transaction((count) => {
    if (count) {
      return count + 1;
    }
    return 1;
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand ios very much, so I can't help you with this error specifically, but I would like to make a suggestion that I think can help you. Don't you think it's better to change your database modeling and perform this operation on the client side?

Answer (score 2):

As highlighted by [@GabrielNexT's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10317633/gabrielnext) comment, this is a similar problem to this other [answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561349/firebase-unhandled-error-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded).

A [`DatabaseReference#transaction()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) call returns a `Promise<`[`TransactionResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.TransactionResult)`>` which contains a nested `DataSnapshot` object, which ultimately is the actual cause of your error.

To correctly unwrap it and return the new count using transactions, you would use following (may require multiple attempts):

```
// Increment the count at the appropriate location in the database
return admin.database(analyticsDb)
  .ref(path)
  .transaction(count => (count || 0) + 1) // concise form of your code
  .then(transactionResult => transactionResult.snapshot.val()) // return the new value
```

Alternatively, the following code could also be used to skip using transactions (single attempt):

```
const counterRef = admin.database(analyticsDb).ref(path);

return counterRef.set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1)) // bumps counter by 1, handled by RTDB server
  .then(() => counterRef.get()) // gets the latest new value
  .then((counterSnapshot) => counterSnapshot.val()) // returns the new value
```