# Firebase functions issue and the difference between .add() vs. .doc().set()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I face the following issue since a few weeks (hasn't been an issue before):

## 1 .add(data)

```
const saveNewDoc = functions.https.onCall((data: NewDocWrite, context: CallableContext) => {
  return adminDb
    .collection(data.collectionPath)
    .add(data.data)
})
```

Document gets successfully created but there's still an error "INTERNAL" returned to the client and also listed in the functions log:

```
Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at baseIteratee (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:3464:26)
    at getIteratee (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:5932:33)
    at Function.map (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9556:31)
    at encode (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:236:18)
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13402:38
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4911:15
    at baseForOwn (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2996:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:7)
    at encode (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:242:18)
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13402:38
```

## 2 .doc().set(data)

Replacing `add()` by `doc().set()` creates the document without any errors.

Any idea why this happens? The "workaround" is simple just using doc().set() but I wonder why there even is the add() then. Can't we just use doc().set() for any new document?

Comment: My first guess would be that there is a problem serializing the object to JSON, although that wouldn't explain why it works with `doc().set()`. What is in your `data`? Can you `console.log()` it?

Comment: Btw: it would be great if you can reproduce with just a node script, without Cloud Functions. At that point we can rule out lots of possible causes.

Comment: What *exactly* is `data` here in the function?

Comment: The answer detail is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51901720/10136855 
 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52569728/10136855


.The `add()` function return a promise and same as `set()`

The simplest way is just use `then` and `catch` to return value to client, even it don't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I've found is simple and clear cut:

`add()` returns `Promise<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference>` while
`set()` returns `Promise

The operation of adding a new document works in either way but once done, the response is sent back to the client, either the document reference or the write result wrapped in a promise. As there is only valid JSON allowed in the response, returning a document reference will result in an error, because it is not in a valid JSON format.

So once the operation is done, either resolve an empty Promise or transform the result into valid JSON before wrapping it in the response - or use set().

Answer (score 0):

with `set` you are selecting a document (you assign your own id) and `add` you are letting firestore to assign an id for you.

A small (not that small) detail here, your callable functio should return a promise that resolves with the response to send to the client, your function returns a promise that is resolved after an operation against the database.

The line your code is complaining about looks like this:

```
if (_.isArray(data)) {
  return _.map(data, encode);
}
```

I would put more attention in the data you are sending more than the method you are using.

```
const saveNewDoc = functions.https.onCall(async (data: NewDocWrite, context: CallableContext) => {
  await adminDb.collection(data.collectionPath).add(data.data)
  // OR
  await adminDb.collection(data.collectionPath).doc().set(data.data)
  return Promise.resolve({ ok: true })

})
```

Actually `doc().set()` is equivalent to `.add()`, I normally use `set` cause I like to have control over the docs Ids I'm setting, but leaving it empty is ok as well. Try that, avoiding returning the promise against the database exec should be good.

Comment: Well, if you use `doc()` without any ID it creates a new document just like .add() does - works perfectly and as far as I know just another recommended way to create a new doc. So where is the actual difference - or is add() in the end just one of the features of doc() and actually not needed?

Comment: Could you be more specific about how the code/function would look like exactly in order to write to the db in the same way while returning the format that's demanded?

Comment: Sure, it would also help a lot to know how data looks like