# 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error with onCall firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I made a firebase cloud function with the `onCall` method. The function takes a uploaded file and resizes it.

I only want the function to return something when the the resizing and upload is done so I know when I can get the `downloadURL`. The function works, it does resize and upload the image. The problem is that it still returns the error

> 'Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' In the firebase functions log.

The Firebase function:

```
exports.resizeImage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   const bucket = 'ezey-aa7b4.appspot.com';
   const contentType = data.contentType;
   const filePath = data.filePath;
   const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
   const dir = path.dirname(filePath);
   console.log("File change detected, function execution started");
   console.log(data);

   const destBucket = gcs.bucket(bucket);
   const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(filePath));
   const thumbName = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'resized-' + fileName);
   const metadata = { contentType: contentType };

   return destBucket.file(filePath).download({
      destination: tmpFilePath
   }).then(() => {
      return sharp(tmpFilePath).resize(500, 500).toFile(thumbName, (err, info) => {
         if(err)
         {
            console.log(err)
         }
         console.log(info)
         destBucket.upload(thumbName, {
            destination: dir + '/resized-' + fileName,
            metadata: metadata
         }).then(() => {
            return {
               uploaded: true
            }
         }).catch((err) => {
            return {
               uploaded: false,
               error: err
            }
         });
      });
   }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
   });
});
```

My application code:

```
   var resizeImage = fb.functions().httpsCallable('resizeImage');

      resizeImage({filePath: file.filePath, contentType: file.contentType}).then(function(result){
         console.log(result)
      }).catch(function(error){
         console.log(error)
      });
```

The given error:

```
Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.map (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9556:31)
    at encode (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:226:18)
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13402:38
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4911:15
    at baseForOwn (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2996:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:7)
    at encode (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:232:18)
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13402:38
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4911:15
    at baseForOwn (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2996:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a return from the upload. So:

```
return destBucket.upload(thumbName, {
```

Without that you're returning the promise from `toFile`, which Cloud Functions doesn't know how to serialize. For more on that, see Doug's answer here: [Firebase Function: Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899198/firebase-function-unhandled-error-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded/51901720)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I changes it but still got the same error. @frank-van-puffelen

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i fixed it! I didn't return the resize itself, only the bucket upload.

Here is my code:

```
return destBucket.file(filePath).download({
      destination: tmpFilePath
   }).then(() => {
      sharp(tmpFilePath).resize(500, 500).toFile(thumbName);

      return destBucket.upload(thumbName, {
         destination: dir + '/resized-' + fileName,
         metadata: metadata
      }).then(() => {
         return {
            uploaded: true
         }
      });

   }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
   });
```

Instead of:

```
return destBucket.file(filePath).download({
      destination: tmpFilePath
   }).then(() => {
      return sharp(tmpFilePath).resize(500, 500).toFile(thumbName, (err, info) => {
         if(err)
         {
            console.log(err)
         }

         console.log(info)

         return destBucket.upload(thumbName, {
            destination: dir + '/resized-' + fileName,
            metadata: metadata
         }).then(() => {
            return {
               uploaded: true
            }
         });

      });
   }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
   });
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I told you in my answer?